# Reminders between dates issue

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

i need to create reminders for tests i make in my app. for each test the user can select repeat interval of daily/weekly and also choose dates range that the reminder will be active between them.

For example:
if i have a test scheduled at 15:00 with daily repeat and i want it to be between 4/4 to 15/4.

When using UILocalNotification i am limited to 64 instances and i **can't** set end date that the reminder will stop firing.

I wanted to know if there is another way to handle this or a way to set an end date? i was thinking about checking event kit but it seems this wont be any good because i don't want the events/reminders to be in the reminders/calendar app of the user.

Thanks for any help,
Gal

Comment: If notification fire than why you have to set the end date??

Answer (score 0):

Store the **endDate** in **userInfo**, which is the property of **UILocalNotification**.

Like `notificationObject.userInfo = endDate//nsdate object`;

Whenever your notification arrives(repeating), check the current date with the enddate from userInfo, if matching, cancel the notification

e.g. `if(enddate same as current date){//cancel the notification}`

Hope this helps.